What does "Time and again my fiery spirit drove me to win a wife" mean?
In Book 9 of the Iliad, when Achilles is rejecting Agamemnon's offer as brought by Odysseus, Achilles says:

If the gods pull me through and I reach home alive,
Peleus needs no help to fetch a bride for me himself.
Plenty of Argive women wait in Hellas and in Phthia,
daughters of lords who rule their citadels in power.
Whomever I want I'll make my cherished wife—at home.
Time and again my fiery spirit drove me to win a wife,
a fine partner to please my heart, to enjoy with her
the treasures my old father Peleus piled high.
The Iliad, book 9: "The Embassy to Achilles", lines 480–487, translation by Robert Fagles (1990)

What does Achilles mean by "Time and again my fiery spirit drove me to win a wife" mean? Does this mean that he has been tempted to settle down with a wife many times? Or that he has, many times, "won" a "wife" - such as Briseis, a spoil of war? The usage of the word "win" here reflects the language used earlier when describing Briseis ("I loved that woman with all my heart, though I won her like a trophy with my spear"), which indicates "trophies", but I don't get the impression that these "trophies" are able to "...enjoy [...] the treasures my old father Peleus piled high".
So what does Achilles mean by this line?

The lines you are asking about are 9.398–399:

ἔνθα δέ μοι μάλα πολλὸν ἐπέσσυτο θυμὸς ἀγήνωρ
γήμαντα μνηστὴν ἄλοχον ἐϊκυῖαν ἄκοιτιν
Homer. Iliad 9.398–399. Perseus Digital Library.

The key verb is ἐπέσσυτο in 9.398 meaning “put in motion”, “set upon”, “hastened towards” (Liddell and Scott). Achilles says that very often (μάλα πολλὸν) his heroic spirit (θυμὸς ἀγήνωρ) set upon (ἐπέσσυτο) marrying a wife. But he does not say that he succeeded in doing so. The phrasing suggests that this was an intention that was never carried out.
As for Fagles’ choice of “win”, the Greek in 9.399 is γήμαντα μνηστὴν ἄλοχον, literally “marrying a wedded wife”, where μνηστὴν means “wedded” or “wooed and won” (Liddell and Scott). By contrast, the word that Fagles translates as “won her like a trophy with my spear” is δουρικτητήν in 9.343, literally “spear-gotten” from δόρυ (spear) + κτητός (gotten). So there is no suggestion in 9.399 that Achilles had intended to capture a woman in the same manner as Briseis: a captive woman would have become his slave or concubine, not his wife. Achilles does use ἄλοχον (wife) to refer to Briseis in 9.336, but this is most likely a rhetorical exaggeration of her status for the sake of his comparison of Agamemnon’s seizure of Briseis to Paris’s of Helen.
Two other translations of 9.398–399, for comparison:

[A. T. Murray] Full often was my proud spirit fain [eager] to take me there a wedded wife, a fitting helpmeet
[Samuel Butler] Many a time was I minded when at home in Phthia to woo and wed a woman who would make me a suitable wife

If there were any legends elaborating on Achilles’ claim here, they no longer survive. Homer says only (19.327) that Achilles has a son Neoptolemus. But later accounts adduce the following story:

When Achilles was nine years old, Calchas declared that Troy could not be taken without him; so Thetis, foreseeing that it was fated he should perish if he went to the war, disguised him in female garb and entrusted him as a maiden to Lycomedes [king of Skyros]. Bred at his court, Achilles had an intrigue with Deidamia, daughter of Lycomedes, and a son Pyrrhus was born to him, who was afterwards called Neoptolemus. But the secret of Achilles was betrayed, and Ulysses, seeking him at the court of Lycomedes, discovered him by the blast of a trumpet. And in that way Achilles went to Troy.
Pseudo-Apollodorus (1st or 2nd century CE). Library 3.13.8. Translated by James George Frazer (1921). Perseus Digital Library.

This story also appears in Ovid (Metamorphoses book 13), Statius (Achilleid book 1), and pseudo-Hyginus (Fabulae 96), and it was dramatized by Euripides in his Skyrioi (which is lost, but we have a papyrus hypothesis). However, none of these accounts suggest that Achilles and Deidamia were married.
